# Add URL parameters to PHP error log on Hostgator

Tags: php, mysql, parameters, error-log

I've got a PHP error_log which return a few MySQL-errors, but in order to replicate and fix those, I need to be able to see which parameters were passed to the page. I have tried to find this using both the PHP error_log file and the Apache logs from my Hostgator hosting, but cannot work out which one belongs to which, as the times don't seem to match up. Is there a way to store the URL with parameters in the error_log, or is there a better way to do this?

Many thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at using:

```
error_log($url);
error_log($param1);
```

You should be able to push to the log any data you wish

Comment: ok nice, where would I place this though, at the top of each file, or?

Comment: Where ever you are in the code you wish to print the value of a variable to the log. eg. $var = 'foo'; error_log($var);

Answer (score 0):

For multiple reasons, including that not all PHP errors may have been triggered from a web-based entry, `error_log` does not have a way to automatically log additional useful information.

For single instances you can log the information you need with `error_log` however I would suggest you use a [logger](https://packagist.org/?query=log) and then modify the output. [Monolog formatter](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/main/doc/02-handlers-formatters-processors.md#formatters) is a solid choice.

Alternatives would be something like [rollbar](https://rollbar.com/) that will gather the surrounding conditions so you can recreate the error.